# Rest: How to stream video (not download)

Tags: rest, video, jersey, video-streaming

Here is the code that instead of streaming the video (which is what I want) downloads the video to the disk.

```java
@GET
@Path("/articleVideo/{videoID}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
public Response getArticleVideo(@PathParam("videoID") int videoID) {

    MediaDAO mediaDAO = new MediaDAO();
    MediaEntity video = mediaDAO.getMediaById(videoID);

    if(video == null) {
        throw new WebApplicationException("Requested user not found");
    }

    File file = new File(video.getLink());

    if (!file.exists()) {
        throw new WebApplicationException(404);
    }

    StreamingOutput out = new StreamingOutput() {
        @Override
        public void write(OutputStream output) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
            try {
                InputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
                IOUtils.copy(input, output);
                output.flush();
            } 
        }
    };

    return Response.ok(out).build();
}
```

I have tried many combinations and looked up many other posts here on stack overflow but none of them is working.